# How to create fade in/out effect on mouse hover over window in C# VS2010?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, fade

I have a login form (Form1) that I want to be faded out untill the user moves over it with the mouse, and when the user leaves the window, it goes back to the initial transparency.

I have tried MouseHover and MouseLeave events but cannot achieve the desired effect, could someone please help me?

Comment: That events will be fired for controls so if your mouse goes over a control your form won't receive any event. You can 1) subscribe for that events in every control (and its descendants) or 2) use a mouse hook. Try to Google for them...

Comment: @Adriano or 3) use a timer to see if the mouse is over the form area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Panel panel1;
    private PictureBox pictureBox1;
    private Timer timer;
    private double opacity_increment;
    private bool mouse_over;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        opacity_increment = 0.1d;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Enabled = true;

        panel1 = new Panel();
        pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();

        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        SuspendLayout();

        panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        panel1.Name = "panel1";
        panel1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(322, 180);
        panel1.TabIndex = 0;
        panel1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(MouseEnterLogic);
        panel1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(MouseLeaveLogic);

        pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
        pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
        pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        pictureBox1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(MouseEnterLogic);
        pictureBox1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(MouseLeaveLogic);

        Controls.Add(panel1);
        panel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);

        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        ResumeLayout();
    }
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouse_over)
        {
            if (Opacity <= 1)
            {
                Opacity += opacity_increment;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Opacity >= 0.5d)
            {
                Opacity -= opacity_increment;
            }
        }
    }
    private void MouseLeaveLogic(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Cursor.Position.X > this.Location.X + this.Width - 10 || Cursor.Position.Y > this.Location.Y + this.Height - 10 || Cursor.Position.X < this.Location.X + 10 || Cursor.Position.Y < this.Location.Y + 30)
            mouse_over = false;
    }
    private void MouseEnterLogic(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mouse_over = true;
    }
    // You don't need overrides because if you have docked panel on the form thus the cursor will never firing these methods (cursor never overlaps the form).
    //protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    MouseEnterLogic(this, e);
    //    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    //}
    //protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    MouseLeaveLogic(this, e);
    //    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    //}
}
```

Comment: Your code fades away when the mouse goes over a control in the form.  Among other issues...

Comment: Now place a control on the edge of the form.  The form's MouseEnter and MouseLeave events won't fire now when the mouse enter's that control's boundary.  :-)

Comment: Why do you need it so close? You can set 12; 12 position for the control for an instance and it will work.

Comment: I'm just showing you potential pitfalls of your solution.  It's not unheard of to have a panel docked in a form, etc.

Comment: You can use OnMouseEnter OnMouseLeave overrides for the docked panel and use the same code. Does it solve?

Comment: I edited the code. It works with docked panel as well.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty new to C# and VS so I don't really fully understand that code, also didn't work before with Timers. I implemented the code and it works ok but for some reason it doesn't take in consideration the window margins, and on the left side I have a picturebox, when I enter/exit the window with the cursor through that side, the fade in/out doesn't work :/

Comment: You can to use the same methods MouseLeaveLogic and MouseEnterLogic for other controls like your picturebox. Just add them into leave/enter event of a control: picturebox.MouseEnter += EventHandler(MouseEnterLogic); picturebox.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(MouseLeaveLogic); i will provide an edit of a code soon.

Comment: Still doesn't work with the new code..also from what I can figure out, the elements that are ON that panel (labels, pictureboxes, buttons) are not taken in consideration, for example if I had a label at the upper margin of the panel it would still remain transparent on mouse hover; isn't there a way to just...put the panel ontop of every other element?


// EDIT: nevermind, I figured out the problem, you  initialised there new components (new picture box for example) instead of using the one I already created, I just deleted the initialization part and now everything is ok.

Comment: Another thing, I have a background image set on the form (it's a login form) and no borders on the window, but sometimes when I exit the window with the mouse, before it fades theres a strage flickering, like, it goes to black for a milisecond then back to normal, I've set the panel to transparent by the way, does anyone know how to fix that flickering problem or why it happens?
Edit: it's almost like the panel becomes visible for a milisecond than becomes transparent.

Comment: You can try remove methods from an event (delegate) which handle the fade from every control which use it when you are clicking "Exit button". It will look like: `private void btn_exit_click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Form.MouseEnter -= EventHandler(MouseEnterLogic); Form.MouseLeave -= EventHandler(MouseLeaveLogic); }`

Comment: Well I don't really understand what you mean but I used a transparent picturebox(pictureboxes are defaultly doublebuffered) that I overlayed on the form and removed the panel, now it stopped flickering on fade in/out but it still flickers on form load